# Problem with Nativescript 7 angular 8 and nativescript-google-maps-sdk

Tags: nativescript, angular8, nativescript-google-maps-sdk

I'm facing this error when trying to dislay google maps on android emulator, using nativescript 7.2.0 Angular 8 and nativescript-google-maps-sdk 3.0.2 :

JS: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: *nativescript_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1*_.Property is not a constructor
JS: TypeError: *nativescript_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1*_.Property is not a constructor
JS:     at Module.../node_modules/nativescript-google-maps-sdk/map-view-common.js (file: node_modules\nativescript-google-maps-sdk\map-view-common.js:275:7)
JS:     at **webpack_require** (file: src\webpack\bootstrap:750:0)
JS:     at fn (file: src\webpack\bootstrap:120:0)
JS:     at Module.../node_modules/nativescript-google-maps-sdk/map-view.js (file: node_modules\nativescript-google-maps-sdk\map-view.android.js:1:0)
JS:     at **webpack_require** (file: src\webpack\bootstrap:750:0)
JS:     at fn (file: src\webpack\bootstrap:120:0)
JS:     at Module../app/home/home.component.ts (file: src\app\home\home.component.ts:1:0)
JS:     at **webpack_require** (f...

If anyone can help
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out the issues on the nativescript-google-maps-sdk github site, particularly [this one](https://github.com/dapriett/nativescript-google-maps-sdk/issues/457).